# Weird extra space in the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

I'm very confused. #top div has a weird extra space in the bottom of it, setting height of course works, but the problem is that I want to add back compatibility, so if a custom font doesn't load, it uses Verdana, which is wider, so it takes more place, and if the navbar gets bigger, it won't properly fit in the #top

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sidebar test</title>
</head>
<style>
div {
border: 1px solid #999;
}

body { font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; }

#navbar {
border-radius: 6px;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navbar ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
float: left;
}

#navbar ul li {
display: inline;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navbar ul a {
float: left;
padding: 10px 18px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.02s;
transition: background-color 0.02s;
}

#navbar ul a:hover {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#navbar ul a:selected {
background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

#content {
padding: 35px 50px 60px 50px;
}

#container {
width: 900px;
margin: 20px auto;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px #d5d5d5;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="container">

<div id="top">
<a href="#"><img alt="logo" height="27px" src="http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/Tphntwm0j/yvemiro.svg"></a>
<div id="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
Content
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a runnable test case: https://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/

Comment: The best way to recognize where an unexplained gap comes from is by inspecting the page (in Chrome, right click -> "Inspect element"). Hovering through the elements you'll usually quickly find what is causing it. Alternatively, consider providing a testable example

Comment: The `style` element is outside of the `head`. I don't believe that matters much, but still.

Comment: Whoops, indeed, I forgot

Comment: Here's a link on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fm8svab1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, inline elements are vertically aligned to the baseline. Now the navbar contains an image and the menu bar next to each other, so it has to shift these up and down a bit in order to align them.

Solution: give these things `vertical-align:middle` (or any other value that doesn't require shifting the blocks out of center).

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
}
#top > a > img {             /* this was added */
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#navbar {
  border-radius: 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;    /* and this */
}
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
#navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar ul a {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.02s;
  transition: background-color 0.02s;
}
#navbar ul a:hover {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
#navbar ul a:selected {
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
}
#content {
  padding: 35px 50px 60px 50px;
}
#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 1px #d5d5d5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="top">
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="logo" height="27" src="http://static.tumblr.com/zicio7x/Tphntwm0j/yvemiro.svg">
    </a>
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, that actually works, such a simple problem and such a simple solution, you actually killed two birds with one stone, because I also wanted to make those two elements on one level, so it'll look good. Thank you a lot :)